# Nextjs build is faild

Tags: next.js

[pls help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brWrx.png)

when running npm run build .I got an error: `./pages/include/WithTransition.js 4:9  Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name`

Comment: And do you think that component _does_ have a display name? Did you read https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/display-name.md?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to WithTransition.js

Make sure you defined the displayName before exporting

```
WithTransition.displayName = 'WithTransition';

export default WithTransition;
```